# Alias multiple DNS entries to one Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on Amazon S3. Lets call it "webstatic.mydomain.com".
I have a DNS alias setup for that bucket 
webstatic.mydomain.com CNAME -> web-static.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com.

This all works great, however for some rather complicated reasons I now need:

webstatic.myOtherDomain.com to point to that same amazon bucket so:

webstatic.myOtherDomain.com CNAME -> web-static.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com.

Fails, as the bucket is not called the same as the referring DNS. Can anyone tell me how to have two different DNS entries pointing to the same amazon bucket?

Answer (score 2):

You can make `webstatic.myOtherDomain.com` a `CNAME` to `webstatic.mydomain.com`. It will be a double `CNAME` but it should work.

Comment: that will not work